# Illustrator: Is it possible to move Guidelines while rearranging artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, guides

as the title says I would like to know if its possible in Illustrator to make the guidlines move with the commmand "Object -> Artboards -> Rearrange..."

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, theres no way you can move the guides with the **Object → Artboards → Rearrange...** What you see is what you get, perhaps in a newer version.

There are two workarounds. One is to release guides to geometry and then remake them into guides, the other is to make a script that does this. If no workaround is good enough for you then there is no solution. Its very hard to affect adobe so we can only give you workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but...

1. Unlock Guides (View > Guides > Uncheck "Lock Guides")
2. Select a guide AND another object that is on the artboard you want the guide to stay with
3. Group the guide and object together (Ctrl + G, or Cmd + G on a Mac)

The guide will move with that artboard when you rearrange. This works in Illustrator CC 2015.